# how to access a function that is a part of nested function such that that inside function can be called?

Tags: python

I have created a function as below,

```
def first():
    print('foo')
    def second():
        print('bar')
```

i want to access the **second()** function directly so that i could print **bar** is there any way to do it?

Comment: `second` *doesn't even exist* until `first()` has been called - and it doesn't return `second` or otherwise store it anywhere that is accessible outside of the function, so there is no later opportunity to call `second()`.

Comment: Why do you have nested functions in the first place?